# How to join two sql statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two queries which return correct results. One of them is:

```
select distinct epr.DepartmentCode 
from [dbo].[EmployeePayRates] epr 
join [dbo].[EmployeeTimecards] et on epr.EmployeeID = et.EmployeeID 
where StoreID = 89
```

It checks all the distinct departments employees ever checked in in the store 89. Query returns:

```
DepartmentCode
1
2
5
```

Second query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    DepartmentCode, count(DISTINCT EmployeeID) 
FROM [dbo].[EmployeeTimecards] 
WHERE EmployeeTimecardDate = '2013-11-25' 
  AND StoreID = 89 
GROUP BY 
   DepartmentCode
```

It returns the number of employees in each department today at the store 89. Table looks like:

```
DepartmentCode          EmployeeCount
1                       17
5                       7
```

And I'm trying to make it look like:

```
DepartmentCode          EmployeeCount
1                       17
2                       0
5                       7
```

I will really appreciate if somebody will show me how to join these queries.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move your first query into a subquery, then `LEFT JOIN` back to your table, and perform the same count:

```
WITH DepartmentCodes AS
(   SELECT  DISTINCT epr.DepartmentCode 
    FROM    [dbo].[EmployeePayRates] epr 
            JOIN [dbo].[EmployeeTimecards] et 
                ON epr.EmployeeID = et.EmployeeID 
    WHERE   StoreID = 89
)
SELECT  dc.DepartmentCode,
        EmployeeCount = COUNT(DISTINCT c.EmployeeID)
FROM    DepartmentCodes dc
        LEFT JOIN [dbo].[EmployeeTimecards]  c
            ON dc.DepartmentCode = c.DepartmentCode
            AND EmployeeTimecardDate = '20131125' 
            AND StoreID = 89 
GROUP BY dc.DepartmentCode;
```

As an aside I changed your string literal date to the culture invariant format `yyyyMMdd` because even the ISO Standard `yyyy-MM-dd` can be misinterpreted as `yyyy-dd-MM` in some regions. Although not the main point of the article [Aaron Bertrand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61305/aaron-bertrand) covers this formatting issue in his article [mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Comment: I think it won't work, since to begin with your `DepartmentCodes` CTE excludes employeepayrates results not having any employeecard associated with. Maybe you don't even need that CTE?

Comment: @Sebas Why not? The query within the CTE is exactly the same as the first query in the question which returns the 3 department codes required, and I only `LEFT JOIN` back to `EmployeeTimecards` so there is no reason that all 3 rows won't be included in the final result. You are however right, a CTE is not required, and in my update I gave a solution that only has the one join.

Comment: @GarethD The second one outputs the wrong data. But the first one works as a charm! Thank you!

Comment: Right, EmployeeTimecardDate is limitating only.

Comment: @DzmitrySevkovich Glad I could help. I have just removed the second query from the answer since it is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I choose to use a Common Table expression to join the two queries.  Check out my CTE article on my blog - http://craftydba.com/?p=1234.

```
--
-- Join cteDeptCode 2 cteEmpPerDept
--
;
with cteDeptCode (DeptCode) as
(
select distinct epr.DepartmentCode 
from [dbo].[EmployeePayRates] epr 
join [dbo].[EmployeeTimecards] et 
on epr.EmployeeID = et.EmployeeID 
where StoreID = 89
),
cteEmpPerDept(DeptCode, EmpCnt) as
(
SELECT DISTINCT 
DepartmentCode, count(DISTINCT EmployeeID) 
FROM [dbo].[EmployeeTimecards] 
WHERE 
EmployeeTimecardDate = '2013-11-25' AND StoreID = 89 
GROUP BY DepartmentCode
)
select d.DeptCode, a.EmpCnt 
from cteDeptCode d 
left join cteEmpPerDept e 
on d.DeptCode = e.DeptCode
```